# SSL Will not Authenticate for domain of

Tags: apache, ssl, webmin

I am running an Ubuntu 12.04 server with Apache 2.2 and OpenSSL 1.01(recent). I am attempting to serve a self signed certificate across for HTTPS browsing. The server is also running webmin, and a tomcat application server.

Currently HTTPS requests do not work for the primary server, returning an er_connection_refused.

I am currently using virtual hosts to specify locations for https connections. HTTPS only works for my webmin portal and not for any other location on the webserver. I had assumed this was a port conflict between miniserv and apache, however there doesn't appear to be any conflict that I can determine. I have checked for other possible webservers that may be using SSL (such as jetty or nginx) but there doesn't appear to be any.

Is there any way to determine which services are associate with which ports. Failing that is there any way to determine which services are currently using SSL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To find out which services are listening on SSL run:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep :443
```

It will generate output like:

```
tcp     0     0 0.0.0.0:443          0.0.0.0:*           LISTEN      1607/https
```

It sounds like it could also be a conflict in the way you have set up SSL for the virtual hosts. Often vhost config can be a bit funny if you're sharing the same certificate for multiple vhosts.

Edit:
Also another good one for finding what is using a given port is:

```
lsof -i :443 | grep LISTEN
```

Which generates output as:

```
httpd      1132 apache    5u  IPv6 22762080      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd      3084 apache    5u  IPv6 22762080      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd      3312 apache    5u  IPv6 22762080      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd      3555 apache    5u  IPv6 22762080      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd      3593 apache    5u  IPv6 22762080      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
```